# Tensor Formula in Hartshorne II.8.20

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensor-products, schemes

Someone in this community should have ask of something similar before, but I found that my question was not answered. The following is an excerpt of Hartshorne II.8.20:

[image]

I would like to ask why the isomorphism
$$\mathscr{I}/\mathscr{I}^2\cong \mathscr{I}_Y\otimes\mathscr{O}_Y$$
is satisfied, where $\mathscr{I}$ is the ideal sheaf used to define the *sheaf of module of relative differential* through $\Delta^*(\mathscr{I}/\mathscr{I}^2)$ with $\Delta$ being the diagonal morphism and $\mathscr{I}_Y$ is the sheaf of ideal corresponding to the closed subscheme $Y$.

Thanks in advance for answering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this case, Hartshorne is being sloppy and using $\mathcal{I}$ and $\mathcal{I}_Y$ interchangably for the sheaf of ideals defining $Y$ as a closed subscheme of $X$ (see Proposition II.8.12 and Theorem II.8.17 for a reminder about what $\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2$ means here). As for an explanation of the isomorphism, recall that $\mathcal{O}_Y=\mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{I}_Y$, so the tensor product is just $\mathcal{I}_Y/\mathcal{I}_Y^2$ by the standard natural isomorphism $M\otimes_R R/I = M/IM$.

Comment: Just one more remark that I would like to ask: when defining the sheaf of module of relative differential forms, is it true that it can be done by taking ANY ideal sheaf of $\Delta(X)$?

Comment: Please clarify your comment - I do not understand what you're asking.

Comment: I mean, suppose $X$ is a scheme over $k$. Then the sheaf of relative differential is defined to be $\Delta^*(\mathscr{I}/\mathscr{I}^2)$, for $\mathscr{I}$ being a sheaf of ideal of $\Delta(X)$. By question is: is the choice of $\mathscr{I}$ specific? Or it is just an arbitrary sheaf of ideal?

Comment: I do not understand how this is related to the question from your original post. Anyways, there is only _one_ sheaf of ideals of $\Delta\subset X\times_k X$ up to the correct notion of isomorphism here, so you need not worry.